# Array property nil despite strong property reference

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

Sorry for the dumb question.  This is my first go with ARC and I am a little confused.

I declare my property as strong:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

I fill it with some test data at init:

```
- (id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    if (self) {

        self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [self.dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"First name", @"Set", @"First set", @"Editiion", @"First edition", nil]];
        [self.dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"Second name", @"Set", @"Second set", @"Editiion", @"Second edition", nil]];
        [self.dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"Third name", @"Set", @"Third set", @"Editiion", @"Third edition", nil]];
    }
    return self;
```

When I come to use it, `self.dataArray` is `nil`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return self.dataArray.count;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, I thought this property would be retained for the life of my object?

Comment: Are you certain initWithWindowNibName is being called and that [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName] doesn't return nil?

Comment: is your init called? It seems like it isn't. Maybe move the code to awakeFromNib or wherever appropriate depending on the class you are subclassing.

Comment: Yes it is, put a break point in the init.

Comment: I'm subclassing NSWindowController

Comment: When stepping though the init, self.array has a count of 3 by the time it hits the return

Comment: @MagicBulletDave: Where are you initialising your table view?? it might be possible that "numberOfRowsInTableView" is getting called even before your array get initialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should try to put your array initialization in `- (void)awakeFromNib`.
Apple documents on this:

`Classes can implement this method to initialize state information after objects have been loaded from an Interface Builder archive (nib file).`

`An awakeFromNib message is sent to each object loaded from the archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.`

In last app that I wrote I set all properties in awakeFromNib and it was working. Try this.

Comment: Hi Ivp this works, thanks! and will accept your answer.  I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here.  I think it might be to do with IB and the wiring (new to IB too).  The Init gets called once.  But it is a another instance that gets the awakeFromNib.

Comment: Check this out. Hope it helps.http://www.quora.com/Cocoa-API/What-is-the-difference-between-initWithCoder-initWithNibName-and-awakeFromNib

Answer (score 0):

Add following code, and set a breakpoint:

```
- (void)setDataArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    _dataArray = array;
}
```

Then debug to check the all positions where invoke the set method.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tip.  The setDataArray is called once, straight after the alloc, init.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Ivp for providing a fix, I am writing this answer to give more detail of why the issue occurred.

In interface builder I had inadvertently used my class twice for the same xib.  Once in *File's Owner* and again in the *Objects* list.  My window was referenced to the File's Owner, but the `dataSource` for the NSTableView was referencing the one in the object's list.

This meant two instances of my class were being created.  Once on the `initWithWindowNibName`: and again when the `NSTableView` was calling methods on it's delegate.

`awakeFromNib:` fixes the problem as the data is being set for both instances.  However to cure it, I removed my class from the *Objects* list and re-wired all referencing Outlets and Actions to the files owner.

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
@interface ClassName()
{
   NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}
@end

-(id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName 
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    if (self) {

       dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       [dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"First name", @"Set", @"First set", @"Editiion", @"First edition", nil]];
       [dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"Second name", @"Set", @"Second set", @"Editiion", @"Second edition", nil]];
       [dataArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"Third name", @"Set", @"Third set", @"Editiion", @"Third edition", nil]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don't make dataArray property. Try this, hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks Maverick.  Not sure I understand what this will achieve - can you let me know your thinking?

Comment: How will making `dataArray` an ivar make a difference??? Do you know anything about ARC or `@properties`??? When you declare a `@property` this will automatically generate the ivar for you and in later xcodes the `@synthesize` is also automatically added for you so no need to add this yourself so your getters and setters are created automatically. If you just did an ivar then you will not have the getters or the setters so this just wouldn't do anything to help with the problem. -1